# how do i transform data in sql or in pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark

input dataset

```
Act status  from                        to
123 1     2011-03-29 00:00:00   2011-03-29 23:59:59
123 1    2011-03-30 00:00:00    2011-03-30 23:59:59
123 1    2011-03-31 00:00:00    2011-03-31 23:59:59
123 0    2011-04-01 00:00:00    2011-04-03 23:59:59
123 0    2011-04-04 00:00:00    2011-04-04 23:59:59
123 0    2011-04-05 00:00:00    2011-04-05 23:59:59
123 1    2011-04-06 00:00:00    2011-04-06 23:59:59
123 1    2011-04-07 00:00:00    2011-04-07 23:59:59
123 1    2011-04-08 00:00:00    2011-04-10 23:59:59
```

I want output to be

```
act status  from                        to 
123 1     2011-03-29 00:00:00   2011-03-31 23:59:59
123 0     2011-04-01 00:00:00   2011-04-05 23:59:59
123 1    2011-04-06 00:00:00    2011-04-10 23:59:59
```

Comment: You should explain in plain words how output should be computed from input, it's not obvious

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lag function to track the `status` change. After applying the lag function, you would use the results to build your rankings and use the rankings as your `groupBy` parameter. For example:

| status | lag | changed | rankings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 5 |

where:

- status : current status
- lag : status from previous row
- changed : 0 if status == lag, otherwise 0
- rankings : cumulative sum of changed

Anyway, here's the answer to your question in SQL.

```
spark.sql('''
SELECT Act, status, from, to
FROM (
    SELECT Act, status, MIN(from) AS from, MAX(to) AS to, rankings
    FROM (
        SELECT *, SUM(changed)  OVER(ORDER BY from) AS rankings
        FROM (
            SELECT *, IF(LAG(status) OVER(PARTITION BY Act ORDER BY from) = status, 0, 1) AS changed
            FROM sample
        )
    )
    GROUP BY 1,2,5
)
''').show()
```

output:

```
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|Act|status|               from|                 to|
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|123|     1|2011-03-29 00:00:00|2011-03-31 23:59:59|
|123|     0|2011-04-01 00:00:00|2011-04-05 23:59:59|
|123|     1|2011-04-06 00:00:00|2011-04-10 23:59:59|
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

And, here's the pyspark version:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, sum, max, min, when
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df2 = df.withColumn("lag_tracker",lag("status",1).over(Window.partitionBy("Act").orderBy("from")))
df2 = df2.withColumn("changed", when(df2.lag_tracker == df2.status, 0).otherwise(1))
df2 = df2.withColumn("rankings", sum("changed").over(Window.orderBy("from")))
df2 = df2.groupBy("Act", "status", "rankings").agg(min("from").alias("from"), max("to").alias("to"))
df2.select("Act", "status", "from", "to").show()
```

output:

```
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|Act|status|               from|                 to|
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|123|     1|2011-03-29 00:00:00|2011-03-31 23:59:59|
|123|     0|2011-04-01 00:00:00|2011-04-05 23:59:59|
|123|     1|2011-04-06 00:00:00|2011-04-10 23:59:59|
+---+------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no gaps in the dates, I would suggest uses the difference of row numbers:

```
select act, status, min(from), max(to)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by act order by from) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by act, status order by from) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by act, status, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  However, if you look at the results from the subquery, you will see that the difference between `seqnum` and `seqnum_2` is constant on adjacent rows with the same status.

Note:  I would advise you to fix your data model so you don't miss the last second on each day.  The `to` datetime of one row should be the same as the `from` datetime of the next row.  When querying, you can use `>=` and `<` to get the values that the row matches.